# How to Increase MessageDlg width in Delphi7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7. I want to change the messageDlg width.

I mean my message test is very long because of that message is displaying in 2 lines but i want to display message only in one line.

Below is my single line of code

```
MessageDlg('i want to display only in oneline i want to display only in oneline i want to display only in oneline i want to display only in oneline i want to display only in oneline',mtError,[mbok],0)
```

and the out put is:
[image]

Above message is displaying in 2 lines but i want to display message only in one line.

Comment: Who wants to read a line of text that stretches off into the distance without a new line? It's almost as though you want to make your user experience worse.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you are right.  but can you please tell me how to do that. I am interested to learn.

Comment: In later versions of Delphi, you'll find that message dialogs have actually been made even smaller for ease of readability. The one in your screenshot is already much larger than I'm comfortable with.

Comment: If it's not broke then why fix it? Just leave it as it is, also just because it appears on two lines for you may not be the case to another user who for example may be using different screen resolution, system fonts and sizes and theme styles etc. Let Windows take care of this for you and don't worry yourself over it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Delphi 7 the `MessageDlg` function is implemented on top of `CreateMessageDialog`. You can call that method and have a `TForm` instance be returned to you. You can then widen that form, widen its label, and then show the form.

```
var
  Form: TForm;
  Label: TLabel;
....
Form := CreateMessageDialog(Msg, mtError, [mbOK]);
try
  Label := Form.FindComponent('Message');
  Label.Width := Label.Width + ExtraWidth;
  Form.ClientWidth := Form.ClientWidth + ExtraWidth;
  Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
  ShowModal;
finally
  Form.Free;
end;
```

All that remains is for you to work out `ExtraWidth`. Look in the implementation of `CreateMessageDialog` for inspiration there. Presumably you'd want to include logic to avoid making the form too wide, spreading beyond the width of a monitor and so on.